# DOM manipulating that I called Framework

Tags: javascript, template, dom, sass, mustache

I'm building a framework like this that can turn SASS-like code into CSS, a template engine like Mustache, a DOM manipulator like React, and a router to add a single page app, and I'm having a performance problem.

I need some help to get it running quickly and maybe some code refactoring if possible.

```
    var Dust = (function() {
    var $Sass = {regex: {url: /@import\s+(?:url\()?\s*(?:['"])?([^'"\)\s]+)(?:['"])?\s*(?:\))?;/g,selector: /([^\s\;\{\}][^\;\{\}]*)\{/g,end: /\}/g,line: /([^\;\{\}]*)\;/g,comment: /\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//g,attribute: /([^\:]+):([^\;]*);/,alt: /(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)|([^\s\;\{\}][^\;\{\}]*(?=\{))|(\})|([^\;\{\}]+\;(?!\s*\*\/))/gim},},
        $Preset = {devider: "__devide__",quotes: "(?=(?:[^'\"`]|[\"'`][^'\"`]*[\"'`])*$)",regex: {imports: /{{\s*#import\s+['|"|`](.*?)['|"|`]\s*}}/g,spacers: /\s*(<\/?[\w\s="/.':;#-\/\?]+>)\s*/gi,escape: /@{{/gi,comment: /{{!--(.*?)--}}/gms,array: /(.*)->(.*)/g,start: "{{",end: "}}",},},
        $Maker = {text: "text",svgs: {svg: true,animate: true,animateMotion: true,"mask-box-width": true,"mask-border-width": true,"shape-image-threshold": true,}},
        $Router = {
            join: function() {
                var separator = "/";
                return separator + arrayFilter(Array.from(arguments).join(separator).split(separator), function(e) {return e.length;}).join(separator);
            },
            map: function(tree, parent, routes) {
                var guard = function() {return true;},fn = function() {},tree = tree || [],routes = routes || [],parent = parent || {path: "",guard: function() {return true;},};
                for (var object of tree) {
                    var _ = {};
                    _.view = object.view;
                    _.path = $Router.join(parent.path, object.path);
                    _.guard = (Verify.fn(object.guard) && object.guard) || (object.guard == "current" && parent.guard) || guard;
                    _.name = object.name;
                    _.fn = object.fn || fn;
                    routes.push(_);
                    $Router.map(object.scope, object, routes);
                }
                return routes;
            },
            path: function(path) {
                return new RegExp("^" + path.replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/{\w+:\w+}/g, "(.+)") + "$");
            },
            match: function(router) {
                var url = (router.hash ? location.hash.substring(1) : location.pathname) || "/";
                if (!router.hash && !url.startsWith("/")) url = "/" + url;
                var potentialMatches = router.routes.map(function(route) {return {route: route,result: url.match($Router.path(route.path)),};});
                var match = potentialMatches.find(function(potentialMatch) {return potentialMatch.result !== null; });
                if (!match) { match = {route: router.routes.find(function(p) {return p.path === "/404";}), result: [url],};}
                return match;
            },
            params: function(match) {
                var values = arrayMap(arraySlice(match.result, 1), function(e) {return e.split("?")[0];});
                var keys = arrayMap(arrayFrom(match.route.path.matchAll(/{(\w+):/g)), function(result) {return result[1];});
                var types = arrayMap(arrayFrom(match.route.path.matchAll(/:(\w+)}/g)), function(result) {return result[1];});
                return objectFromEntries(arrayMap(keys, function(key, i) {
                    var val = void 0;
                    switch (types[i].toLowerCase()) {
                        case "str":
                            val = String(values[i]);
                            break;
                        case "int":
                            val = parseInt(values[i]);
                            break;
                        case "num":
                            val = Number(values[i]);
                            break;
                        case "real":
                            val = parseFloat(values[i]);
                            break;
                        case "bool":
                            val = Boolean(values[i]);
                            break;
                        case "any":
                        default:
                            val = values[i];
                            break;
                    }
                    return [key, val];
                }));
            }
        },
        $HELPERS = {},$Navigate;
    var _toArray = function(array) {
            var _array = [];
            for (var object of array) {
                _array.push(object);
            }
            return _array
        },
        arrayFrom = function(array, callback, args) {
            if ("next" in array) array = _toArray(array);
            if (Verify.type(array) === "set") array = _toArray(array.values());
            if (Verify.obj(array) && Verify.nbr(array.length)) {
                for (var len = array.length, _array = [], i = 0; i < len; i++) _array.push(undefined);
                array = _array;
            }
            for (var len = array.length, _array = [], i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                _array.push(Verify.fn(callback) ? callback.call(args, array[i], i, array) : array[i]);
            }
            return _array;
        },
        arrayMap = function(array, callback, args) {
            for (var len = array.length, _array = [], i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                _array[i] = callback.call(args, array[i], i, array);
            }
            return _array;
        },
        arrayFilter = function(array, callback, args) {
            for (var len = array.length, _array = [], i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (callback.call(args, array[i], i, array))
                    _array.push(array[i]);
            }
            return _array;
        },
        arrayFind = function(array, callback, args) {
            for (var len = array.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (callback.call(args, array[i], i, array))
                    return array[i];
            }
            return null;
        },
        arraySort = function(array, callback, args) {
            for (var len = array.length - 1, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                for (var _len = array.length, _i = i + 1; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    if (callback.call(args, array[i], array[_i], i, array) > 0) {
                        var temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[_i];
                        array[_i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return array;
        },
        arrayEach = function(array, callback, args) {
            for (var len = array.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                callback.call(args, array[i], i, array);
            }
        },
        arrayReduce = function(array, callback, start, args) {
            for (var len = array.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                start = callback.call(args, start, array[i], i, array);
            }
            return start;
        },
        arraySlice = function(array, start, end) {
            for (var len = end || array.length, _array = [], i = start || 0; i < len; i++) {
                _array.push(array[i]);
            }
            return _array;
        },
        arrayConcat = function() {
            for (var len = arguments.length, array = [], i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                for (var _array = arguments[i], _len = _array.length, _i = 0; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    array.push(_array[_i]);
                }
            }
            return array;
        };
    var objectProperty = function(object, property, descriptor) {
            Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ && ('get' in descriptor) && Object.prototype.__defineGetter__.call(object, property, descriptor.get);
            Object.prototype.__defineSetter__ && ('set' in descriptor) && Object.prototype.__defineSetter__.call(object, property, descriptor.set);
            ('value' in descriptor) && (object[property] = descriptor.value);
            return object;
        },
        objectKeys = function(object) {
            var key, array = [];
            for (key in object) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key) && array.push(key);
            return array;
        },
        objectValues = function(object) {
            var key, array = [];
            for (key in object) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key) && array.push(object[key]);
            return array;
        },
        objectEntries = function(object) {
            var key, array = [];
            for (key in object) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key) && array.push([key, object[key]]);
            return array;
        },
        objectFromEntries = function(array) {
            for (var len = array.length, object = {}, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                Verify.arr(array[i]) && (array[i].length == 2) && (object[array[i][0]] = array[i][1]);
            }
            return object;
        }
    var execArrayFns = function(self, name) {
            const current = self[name];
            for (let fn of current) fn();
        }
    var Verify = (function() {
        function Verify() {}
        Verify.type = function(element) {return Object.prototype.toString.call(element).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase();}
        Verify.null = function(element) {return this.type(element) === "null";}
        Verify.undefined = function(element) {return this.type(element) === "undefined";}
        Verify.str = function(element) {return this.type(element) === "string";}
        Verify.nbr = function(element) {return this.type(element) === "number";}
        Verify.obj = function(element) {return this.type(element) === "object";}
        Verify.arr = function(element) {return this.type(element) === "array";}
        Verify.fn = function(element) {return this.type(element) === "function";}
        Verify.absent = function(element) {return (this.null(element) || this.undefined(element) ||(this.nbr(element) && isNaN(element)) ||(this.str(element) && element === "") ||(this.arr(element) && element.length === 0) ||(this.obj(element) && objectKeys(element).length === 0));}
        Verify.present = function(element) {return !this.absent(element);}
        return Verify;
    })();
    var Fiber = (function() {
        function Fiber(props) {
            this.type = props.type && props.type.toLowerCase();
            this.props = props.props;
        }
        Fiber.prototype.isText = function() {
            return this.type === $Maker.text;
        }
        Fiber.prototype.isSvg = function() {
            return this.type in $Maker.svgs;
        }
        return Fiber;
    })();
    var Instance = (function() {
        function Instance(props) {
            this.dom = props.dom;
            this.fiber = props.fiber;
            this.children = props.children;
        }
        return Instance;
    })();
    var Import = (function() {
        function Import(url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        Import.prototype.string = function() {
            return `@import url("${this.url}");`;
        }
        return Import;
    })();
    var Font = (function() {
        function Font(props) {
            this.name = props.name;
            this.properties = props.properties;
        }
        Font.prototype.string = function() {
            return `@face-font {${arrayMap(this.properties, function (e) {
            return e.string();
        }).join("")}}`;
        }
        return Font;
    })();
    var Variable = (function() {
        function Variable(props) {
            this.name = props.name;
            this.value = props.value;
        }
        return Variable;
    })();
    var Mixin = (function() {
        function Mixin(props) {
            this.name = props.name;
            this.properties = props.properties;
        }
        return Mixin;
    })();
    var Block = (function() {
        function Block(props) {
            this.selector = props.selector;
            this.properties = props.properties;
            this.index = props.index;
        }
        Block.prototype.string = function() {
            return `${this.selector}{${arrayMap(this.properties, function (e) {
            return e.string();
        }).join("")}}`;
        }
        return Block;
    })();
    var Property = (function() {
        function Property(props) {
            this.name = props.name;
            this.value = props.value;
        }
        Property.prototype.string = function() {
            return `${this.name}:${this.value};`;
        }
        return Property;
    })();
    var Frame = (function() {
        function Frame(props) {
            this.name = props.name;
            this.properties = props.properties;
        }
        Frame.prototype.string = function() {
            var self = this;
            return arrayMap(["-webkit-", ""], function(frame) {
                return `@${frame}keyframes ${self.name}{${arrayMap(self.properties, function (e) {
                return e.string();
            }).join("")}}`;
            }).join("");
        }
        return Frame;
    })();
    var Media = (function() {
        function Media(props) {
            this.condition = props.condition;
            this.properties = props.properties;
        }
        Media.prototype.string = function() {
            return `@media ${this.condition}{${arrayMap(this.properties, function (e) {
            return e.string();
        }).join("")}}`
        }
        return Media;
    })();
    var Sass = (function() {
        var prefixList = function(property) {
            return Sass.PREFIX_NAMES[property] || [];
        }
        function Sass(template) {
            this.entry = template.replace(/(\n|\s)+/g, " ");
            this.variables = [];
            this.imports = [];
            this.frames = [];
            this.mixins = [];
            this.medias = [];
            this.errors = [];
            this.fonts = [];
            this.tree = [];
            this.count = 0;
            this._exec();
        }
        Sass.prototype._exec = function() {
            var self = this;
            this._extract();
            this.tree = this._parse(this.tree);
            arrayEach(this.fonts, function(font) {
                var props = [];
                for (var prop in font.properties)
                    if (prop !== "@index")
                        props.push(new Property({
                            name: prop,
                            value: font.properties[prop]
                        }));
                font.properties = props;
            });
            arrayEach(this.medias, function(block) {
                block.properties = self._parse(block.properties);
            });
            arrayEach(this.frames, function(block) {
                block.properties = self._parse(block.properties);
            });
        }
        Sass.prototype._object = function() {
            var sheet = {},
                match = null,
                entry = this.entry.replace($Sass.regex.url, function(_, s) {
                    return `@import: "${encodeURIComponent(s)}";`;
                })
                .replace($Sass.regex.comment, '')
                .replace(/(@include)/g, "$1:");
            while ((match = $Sass.regex.alt.exec(entry)) != null) {
                if (Verify.present(match[ /*selector*/ 2])) {
                    var name = match[ /*selector*/ 2].trim(),
                        id = String(this.count++),
                        _sheet = this._object(entry);
                    _sheet["@index"] = id;
                    sheet[name] = _sheet;
                } else if (Verify.present(match[ /*end*/ 3])) {
                    return sheet;
                } else if (Verify.present(match[ /*attr*/ 4])) {
                    var line = match[ /*attr*/ 4].trim(),
                        attr = $Sass.regex.attribute.exec(line);
                    if (attr) {
                        var name = attr[1].trim(),
                            value = attr[2].trim();
                        sheet[name] = value;
                        name === "@import" && this.count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return sheet;
        }
        Sass.prototype._extract = function() {
            var self = this,
                tree = this._object();
            arrayEach(objectKeys(tree), function(key) {
                var found = false;
                if (key[0] === "$") {
                    self.variables.push(new Variable({
                        name: key.substring(1),
                        value: tree[key],
                    }));
                    found = true;
                } else if (key.slice(1, 7) === "import") {
                    self.imports.push(new Import(decodeURIComponent(tree[key].replace(/["'`]/g, ""))));
                    found = true;
                } else if (key.slice(1, 6) === "mixin") {
                    self.mixins.push(new Mixin({
                        name: key.substring(6).trim(),
                        properties: Object.assign({}, tree[key])
                    }));
                    found = true;
                } else if (key.slice(1, 6) === "media") {
                    self.medias.push(new Media({
                        condition: key[6] === "." ? Sass.BREAK_POINTS[key.substring(7).trim()] : key.substring(6).trim(),
                        properties: Object.assign({}, self._variable(self._mixin(tree[key])))
                    }));
                    found = true;
                } else if (key.slice(1, 6) === "frame") {
                    self.frames.push(new Frame({
                        name: key.substring(6).trim(),
                        properties: Object.assign({}, self._variable(self._mixin(tree[key])))
                    }));
                    found = true;
                } else if (key.slice(1, 5) === "font") {
                    var font = key.substring(6).trim();
                    tree[key]["font-family"] = '"' + font + '"';
                    self.fonts.push(new Font({
                        name: font,
                        properties: Object.assign({}, self._variable(self._mixin(tree[key])))
                    }));
                    found = true;
                }
                if (found)
                    delete tree[key];
            });
            this.tree = this._variable(this._mixin(tree));
        }
        Sass.prototype._property = function(tree, parent, _tree) {
            var self = this,
                properties = [];
            arrayEach(objectKeys(tree), function(key) {
                if (Verify.obj(tree[key])) {
                    var _ = [],
                        selector = arrayMap(key.split(","), function(e) {
                            return e.trim();
                        });
                    for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < selector.length; j++) {
                            var text = parent[i] + (selector[j][0] === "&" ? selector[j].substring(1) : " " + selector[j]);
                            _.push(text);
                        }
                    }
                    _tree.push({
                        selector: _,
                        properties: self._property(tree[key], _, _tree)
                    });
                } else {
                    arrayEach(prefixList(key), function(prop) {
                        properties.push(new Property({
                            name: prop + key,
                            value: tree[key],
                        }));
                    });
                    properties.push(new Property({
                        name: key,
                        value: tree[key],
                    }));
                }
            });
            return properties;
        }
        Sass.prototype._clean = function(tree) {
            tree = arrayFilter(tree, function(e) {
                return e.selector[0] !== "@index";
            });
            tree = arraySort(tree, function(a, b) {
                var apos = parseInt(arrayFind(a.properties, function(e) {
                    return e.name === "@index";
                }).value);
                var bpos = parseInt(arrayFind(b.properties, function(e) {
                    return e.name === "@index";
                }).value);
                return apos - bpos;
            });
            tree = arrayMap(tree, function(e) {
                var position, props = [];
                arrayEach(e.properties, function(e, i) {
                    if (e.name === "@index") position = e.value;
                    else props.push(e);
                });
                return (new Block({
                    properties: props,
                    selector: e.selector.join(),
                    index: parseInt(position),
                }));
            });
            tree = arrayFilter(tree, function(e) {
                return e.properties.length > 0;
            });
            return tree;
        }
        Sass.prototype._variable = function(tree) {
            var remove, error, self = this;
            arrayEach(objectKeys(tree), function(key) {
                if (Verify.obj(tree[key])) {
                    tree[key] = self._variable(tree[key]);
                } else {
                    tree[key] = tree[key].replace(/\$([A-za-z0-9_-]+)/g, function(_, s) {
                        var _var = arrayFind(self.variables, function(e) {
                            return e.name === s;
                        });
                        if (!_var)(remove = true) && (error = `variables does not include "${s}"`) && !self.errors.includes(error) && self.errors.push(error) && console.error(error);
                        else return _var.value;
                    });
                    remove && delete tree[key] && (remove = null);
                }
            });
            return tree;
        }
        Sass.prototype._mixin = function(tree) {
            var error, self = this,
                _tree = {};
            arrayEach(objectKeys(tree), function(key) {
                if (Verify.obj(tree[key])) {
                    _tree[key] = self._mixin(tree[key]);
                } else {
                    if (key === "@include") {
                        var names = arrayMap(tree[key].split(","), function(e) {
                            return e.trim();
                        });
                        arrayEach(names, function(name) {
                            var object = arrayFind(self.mixins, function(e) {
                                return e.name === name;
                            });
                            if (object && object.properties) {
                                _tree = Object.assign({}, _tree, self._mixin(object.properties));
                            } else(error = `@mixins does not include "${name}"`) && !self.errors.includes(error) && self.errors.push(error) && console.error(error);
                        });
                    } else {
                        _tree[key] = tree[key];
                    }
                }
            });
            return _tree;
        }
        Sass.prototype._parse = function(tree) {
            var self = this,
                _tree = [];
            arrayEach(objectKeys(tree), function(key) {
                if (Verify.obj(tree[key])) {
                    var selector = arrayMap(key.split(","), function(e) {
                        return e.trim();
                    });
                    _tree.push({
                        selector: selector,
                        properties: self._property(tree[key], selector, _tree),
                    });
                }
            });
            return this._clean(_tree);
        }
        Sass.prototype.string = function() {
            var self = this,
                stylesheet = arrayMap(this.imports, function(e) {
                    return e.string();
                });
            arrayEach(this.fonts, function(font) {
                stylesheet.push(self._parse({
                    "@font-face": font.properties
                })[0].string());
            });
            arrayEach(this.tree, function(block) {
                stylesheet.push(block.string());
            });
            arrayEach(this.medias, function(frame) {
                stylesheet.push(frame.string());
            });
            arrayEach(this.frames, function(block) {
                stylesheet.push(block.string());
            });
            return stylesheet.join("");
        }
        Sass.BREAK_POINTS = {
            sm: "(min-width:640px)",
            md: "(min-width:768px)",
            lg: "(min-width:1024px)",
            xl: "(min-width:1280px)",
        }
        Sass.PREFIX_NAMES = {
            "align-content": ["-webkit-", "-ms-", "-moz-"],
            "align-items": ["-webkit-", "-ms-", "-moz-"],
            "user-drag": ["-webkit-", "-khtml-"],
            "wrap-flow": ["-webkit-"],
            "wrap-through": ["-webkit-"],
            "zoom": ["-ms-"]
        }
        return Sass;
    })();
    var Preset = (function() {
        var modeType, memory = {},
            _regex = [
                [$Preset.regex.comment, ""],
                [$Preset.regex.escape, "\\{\\{"],
                [$Preset.regex.spacers, function(_, t) {
                    return t.trim();
                }]
            ],
            systemFns = {
                each(obj, func) {
                    if (obj === null) {
                        return obj;
                    }
                    var index = -1;
                    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
                        var length = obj.length,
                            count = 1;
                        while (++index < length) {
                            if (func(index, obj[index], {index: index, round: count, odd: index % 2 > 0, even: index % 2 === 0, first: index === 0, last: count === length,}) === false) {
                                break;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    var key = Object.keys(obj),
                        length = key.length,
                        count = 1;
                    while (++index < length) {
                        if (func(key[index], obj[key[index]], {index: index,round: count,odd: index % 2 > 0,even: index % 2 === 0,first: index === 0,last: count === length,}) === false) {
                            break;
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                },
                range(from, to, inc, func) {
                    to = inc ? (from < to ? to + 1 : to - 1) : to;
                    for (var i = from; from < to ? i < to : i > to; from < to ? i++ : i--) {
                        func(i, {index: i,round: i + 1,odd: i % 2 > 0,even: i % 2 === 0,first: i === from,last: i === from < to ? i - 1 : i + 1});
                    }
                },
                length(obj) {
                    if (obj === null) return obj;
                    if (Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.length;
                    Object.keys(obj).length
                }
            },
            mode = {
                if (args) {
                    modeType = "if";
                    return "if(" + args.join(" ") + "){";
                },
                elif(args) {return "} else if(" + args.join(" ") + "){";},
                else() {return (modeType === "for" ? "});" : "") + "}else{";},
                unless(args) {return "if(!(" + args.join(" ") + ")){";},
                case (args) {return "break;case " + args.join(" ") + ":";},
                default () {return "break;default:";},
            },
            loop = {
                while (args) {return "while(" + args.join(" ") + "){";},
                untill(args) {return "while(!(" + args.join(" ") + ")){";},
                switch (args) {return "switch(" + args.join(" ") + "){";},
                range(args) {return "$RANGE(" + args[2] + "," + args[4] + "," + args.includes("through") + ", function(" + args[0] + ", $LOOP){";},
                each(args, key, value) {return "$EACH(" + args[0] + ",function(" + key + "," + value + ", $LOOP){";},
                forelse(args, key, value) {
                    modeType = "for";
                    return "if($LENGTH(" + args[0] + ")){$EACH(" + args[0] + ",function(" + key + "," + value + ", $LOOP){";
                },
            },
            rule = {
                var (args) {return "var " + args.join(" ") + ";";},
                alert(args) {return "alert(" + args.join(" ") + ");";},
                console(args, type) {
                    type = type || "log";
                    return "console." + type + "(" + args.join(" ") + ");";
                }
            };
        var endAction = function(type) { return (type == 2 ? "break;" : "") + "}" + (type == 1 ? ");" : "");},
            regexCreate = function() {
                var flag = arguments[0],
                    args = arrayConcat([], arraySlice(arrayFrom(arguments), 1));
                return new RegExp(args.join(""), flag);
            },
            regexReplace = function() {
                var line = arguments[0],
                    regexArray = arrayConcat([], arraySlice(arrayFrom(arguments), 1));
                for (var i = 0, len = regexArray.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var regex = regexArray[i][0],
                        replace = regexArray[i][1];
                    line = line.replace(regex, replace);
                }
                return line;
            }

        function Preset(entry, data, async) {
            this.entry = regexReplace.apply(null, arrayConcat([this._cleanHtml(entry)], _regex));
            this.data = data || {};
            this.async = async || false;
            this._count = 0;
        }
        Preset.prototype._globalProps = function(line) {
            return regexReplace(line, [regexCreate("g", "(@loop)", $Preset.quotes), "$LOOP"], [regexCreate("g", "(@self)", $Preset.quotes), "$SELF"], [regexCreate("g", "(@)", $Preset.quotes), "$HELPERS."], [regexCreate("g", "([.]+[\\w\\d-_]+)", $Preset.quotes), function(obj) {
                return "['" + obj.substring(1) + "']";
            }]);
        }
        Preset.prototype._lastCharAtIndex = function(string, index) {
            if (string[index + 2] === $Preset.regex.end[0]) index = index + 1;
            else return index;
            return this._lastCharAtIndex(string, index);
        }
        Preset.prototype._cleanHtml = function(string) {
            return regexReplace(string.trim(), [/&lt;/g, "<"], [/&gt;/g, ">"], [/&quot;/g, '"'], [/&#39;/g, "'"], [/&amp;/g, "&"], [/\n/g, ""], [/\s+/g, " "]);
        }
        Preset.prototype._arraySyntax = function(array) {
            var match = null,
                key = "_",
                value = array.slice(2).join(" ");
            if (match = $Preset.regex.array.exec(value)) {
                key = match[1];
                value = match[2];
            }
            return {
                key,
                value
            };
        }
        Preset.prototype._logicSyntax = function(array) {
            var self = this;
            return arrayMap(arrayFilter(array, function(line) {
                return line && line.length > 0;
            }), function(line) {
                line = self._globalProps(line);
                if (line[0] !== "#") return "$TXT+=\"" + $Preset.devider + "\";$JSX.push(" + line + ");";
                var args = arrayMap(line
                        .substring(1)
                        .split(" "),
                        function(arg) {
                            return arg.trim();
                        }),
                    act = args.shift(),
                    {
                        key,
                        value
                    } = self._arraySyntax(args);
                switch (act) {
                    case "set":
                        return rule.var(args);
                    case "alert":
                        return rule.alert(args);
                    case "log":
                    case "info":
                    case "warn":
                    case "error":
                    case "debug":
                        return rule.console(args, act);
                    case "if":
                        return mode.if(args);
                    case "elif":
                        return mode.elif(args);
                    case "else":
                        return mode.else();
                    case "unless":
                        return mode.unless(args);
                    case "case":
                        return mode.case(args);
                    case "default":
                        return mode.default();
                    case "while":
                        return loop.while(args);
                    case "until":
                        return loop.untill(args);
                    case "switch":
                        return loop.switch(args);
                    case "range":
                        return loop.range(args);
                    case "each":
                        return loop.each(args, key, value);
                    case "forelse":
                        return loop.forelse(args, key, value);
                    case "/each":
                    case "/range":
                        return endAction(1);
                    case "/switch":
                        return endAction(2);
                    case "/if":
                    case "/while":
                    case "/unless":
                    case "/until":
                    case "/forelse":
                        return endAction();
                    case "code":
                        return args.join(" ");
                }
            });
        }
        Preset.prototype._bindToObject = function(object) {
            for (var fn in object) {
                if (Verify.fn(object[fn]))
                    object[fn] = object[fn].bind(this.data);
                else this._bindToObject(object[fn]);
            }
        }
        Preset.prototype._switchType = function(templateArray, isHtml) {
            if (isHtml) {
                var parts = templateArray.shift();
                return parts.reduce(function(acc, part, i) {
                    return acc + part + (templateArray[i] || "");
                }, "");
            }
            return (new(Function.prototype.bind.apply(Jsx, arrayConcat([null], templateArray)))).exec();
        }
        Preset.prototype._switchAsync = function(type) {
            if (this.async) {
                var self = this;
                return new Promise(async function(resolve) {
                    self.entry = await self._insertHtml(self.entry);
                    resolve(self._switchType(self._compile(self.entry), type));
                });
            }
            return this._switchType(this._compile(this.entry), type);
        }
        Preset.prototype._parse = function(template) {
            var data = {
                    txt: [],
                    jsx: [],
                },
                state = $Preset.regex.start,
                code,
                index = -1;
            while (template.length) {
                index = template.indexOf(state);
                if (index > -1) {
                    if (state === $Preset.regex.start) {
                        code = template.substring(0, index);
                        data.txt.push(code);
                        template = template.substring(index);
                        state = $Preset.regex.end;
                    } else {
                        index = this._lastCharAtIndex(template, index);
                        code = template.substring(state.length, index).trim();
                        data.jsx.push(code);
                        template = template.substring(index + state.length);
                        state = $Preset.regex.start;
                    }
                } else {
                    template.trim().length && data[state == $Preset.regex.start ? "txt" : "jsx"].push(template);
                    template = "";
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
        Preset.prototype._tokenize = function(string) {
            var code = "",
                data = this._parse(string);
            data.jsx = this._logicSyntax(data.jsx);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.txt.length; i++) {
                var prejsx = data.jsx[i - 1],
                    curjsx = data.jsx[i],
                    curtxt = data.txt[i];
                code += "$TXT+=`" + curtxt + "`;";
                if (curjsx && prejsx && curjsx.startsWith("break;") && prejsx.startsWith("switch"))
                    code += curjsx.substring(6);
                else
                    code += curjsx;
            }
            return code;
        }
        Preset.prototype._compile = function() {
            this._bindToObject($HELPERS);
            var str = this._tokenize(this.entry),
                res = new Function(
                    "",
                    regexReplace("return function($SELF, $HELPERS) {" +
                        "var $TXT = '', $JSX = [], $EACH = function " + systemFns.each.toString() +
                        ", $RANGE = function " + systemFns.range.toString() + ", $LENGTH = function " +
                        systemFns.length.toString() + "; with($SELF || {}) { try {" + str +
                        " } catch(e) { console.error(e); }}return [$TXT.split('" + $Preset.devider + "'), ...$JSX];}", [/\s+/g, " "])
                )()(this.data, $HELPERS);
            return res;
        }
        Preset.prototype._importHtml = async function(path) {
            var newpath = "/views/" + path.replaceAll(".", "/") + ".dust.html";
            if (!memory[path]) {
                var r = await fetch(newpath);
                memory[path] = r.status === 200 ? regexReplace.apply(null, arrayConcat([this._cleanHtml(await r.text())], _regex)) : "";
            }
            return memory[path];
        }
        Preset.prototype._insertHtml = async function(template) {
            var matches = [],
                self = this;
            template = regexReplace(template, [$Preset.regex.imports, function(_, path) {
                var hold = "___import__placement__code__" + (self._count++) + "___"
                matches.push({
                    path,
                    hold
                });
                return hold;
            }]);
            for (var match of matches) {
                var _template = await this._importHtml(match.path);
                template = template.replace(match.hold, _template);
                template = await this._insertHtml(template);
            }
            return template;
        }
        Preset.prototype.exec = function() {
            return this._switchAsync();
        }
        Preset.prototype.string = function() {
            return this._switchAsync(true);
        }
        return Preset;
    })();
    var Jsx = (function() {
        function Jsx(entry) {
            this.entry = entry;
            this.props = arraySlice(arrayFrom(arguments), 1);
        }
        Jsx.prototype._props = function(line) {
            var attrs = line.replace(/<(\/?)(\w+)\s*|\s*(\/?)>/g, "").split(new RegExp("\\s+" + $Preset.quotes));
            attrs = arrayReduce(attrs, function(acc, attr, i) {
                if (!attr.length) return acc;
                return acc.push(attr.replace(/[`'"]/g, "")) && acc;
            }, []);
            for (var len = attrs.length, _props = {}, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var [name, value = ""] = attrs[i].split("=");
                _props[name] = value;
            }
            return _props;
        }
        Jsx.prototype._replace = function(attrs, props) {
            var self = this,
                _props = {};
            for (var [name, value] of objectEntries(attrs)) {
                if (name.includes("__code__joiner__")) {
                    var [_name, _value = ""] = name.replace(/__code__joiner__/g, function(_, s) {
                        return props[self._count++];
                    }).trim().split("=");
                    _name.length && (_props[_name] = _value.replace(/["'`](.*?)["'`]/g, "$1"));
                } else if (value === "__code__joiner__") {
                    var j = this._count++;
                    _props[name] = Verify.str(props[j]) ? props[j].trim() : props[j];
                } else {
                    _props[name] = value.replace(/__code__joiner__/g, function() {
                        return props[self._count++]
                    }).trim();
                }
            }
            return _props;
        }
        Jsx.prototype._tokenize = function(template, props) {
            var match,tokens = [],lastIndex = 0,regex = /<(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\s*.*?\s*(\/?)>/g;
            while ((match = regex.exec(template))) {
                var tagStart = match.index,tagEnd = regex.lastIndex,text = template.slice(lastIndex, tagStart),type = match[1].length ? "closing" : "opening",unique = match[1].length ? -1 : 1,single = match[3] ? true : false,name = match[2];
                if (text.trim().length > 0) {tokens.push({type: 'texting',unique: 0,content: text}); }
                tokens.push({type: type,unique: unique,tag: name.toLowerCase(),attributes: this._props(match[0], props),content: match[0] });
                if (single) {tokens.push({type: "closing",tag: name.toLowerCase(),attributes: {},});}
                lastIndex = tagEnd;
            }
            var remainingText = template.slice(lastIndex);
            if (remainingText.trim().length > 0) {tokens.push({type: 'texting',unique: 0,content: remainingText}); }
            return arrayConcat([{ type: "opening", tag: "stack", attributes: {},}], tokens, [{ type: "closing", tag: "stack", attributes: {},}]);
        }
        Jsx.prototype._parse = function(tokens, props) {
            var self = this,
                stack = [],
                result = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                var token = tokens[i];
                if (token.type === "opening") {
                    var node = new Fiber({
                        type: token.tag,
                        props: Object.assign(this._replace(token.attributes, props), {children: [] })
                    });
                    if (stack.length === 0) {result.push(node);
                    } else { stack[stack.length - 1].props.children.push(node);}
                    stack.push(node);
                } else if (token.type === "closing") {
                    var node = stack.pop();
                    if (node.type !== token.tag) {throw new Error(`Unexpected closing tag: ${token.tag}`);}
                    if (stack.length === 0) {return result[0].props.children;}
                } else if (token.type === "texting") {
                    var node = new Fiber({
                        type: "text",
                        props: Object.assign({
                            textContent: token.content.replace(/__code__joiner__/g, function() {return props[self._count++];}).trim()
                        }, {children: []});
                    });
                    if (stack.length === 0) {result.push(node);
                    } else {stack[stack.length - 1].props.children.push(node);}
                }
            }
            throw new Error("Unclosed tags");
        }
        Jsx.prototype.exec = function() {
            this._count = 0;
            var template = this.entry.join("__code__joiner__"),
                tokens = this._tokenize(template),
                tree = this._parse(tokens, this.props);
            delete this._count;
            return tree;
        }
        return Jsx;
    })();
    var Maker = (function() {
        function Maker(container, tree) {
            this.container = container;
            this.instance = null;
            this.tree = tree;
            this.refs = {};
        }
        Maker.prototype._flat = function() {
            var self = this;
            arrayReduce(array, function(flat, toFlatten) {return arrayConcat(flat, Verify.arr(toFlatten) ? self._flat(toFlatten) : toFlatten);}, []);
        }
        Maker.prototype._create = function(fiber) {
            var {type,props} = fiber, isTextElement = type === $Maker.text, dom = isTextElement ? document.createTextNode('') : type in $Maker.svgs ?
                document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", type) : document.createElement(type), children = this._children({dom}, fiber);
            this._props(dom, {}, props);
            return new Instance({dom,fiber,children,});
        }
        Maker.prototype._reconcile = function(parentDom, oldNode, fiber) {
            var node, self = this;
            if (oldNode == null) {
                if (Verify.arr(fiber)) {
                    node = arrayMap(fiber, function(e) { return self._create(e);});
                    arrayEach(node, function(e) {parentDom.appendChild(e.dom);});
                } else node = this._create(fiber);
                if (Verify.arr(node.dom)) {
                    var doms = this._flat(node.dom);
                    arrayEach(doms, function(e) {parentDom.appendChild(e);});
                } else if (node.dom) {parentDom.appendChild(node.dom);}
                return node;
            } else if (fiber == null) {
                if (Verify.arr(oldNode)) {
                    arrayEach(oldNode, function(e) {parentDom.removeChild(e.dom);});
                } else if (oldNode.dom) {parentDom.removeChild(oldNode.dom);}
                return null;
            } else if (Verify.arr(oldNode) && Verify.arr(fiber)) {
                return this._children({dom: parentDom,children: oldNode}, {props: { children: fiber}});
            } else if ((oldNode.fiber || {}).type !== fiber.type) {
                var node = this._create(fiber);
                if (oldNode.dom || oldNode[0].dom) {
                    parentDom.replaceChild(node.dom, oldNode.dom || oldNode[0].dom);
                }
                return node;
            } else if (typeof fiber.type === 'string') {
                oldNode.children = this._children(oldNode, fiber);
                this._props(oldNode.dom, oldNode.fiber.props, fiber.props);
                oldNode.fiber = fiber;
                return oldNode;
            }
        }
        Maker.prototype._children = function(oldNode, fiber) {
            var oldChildNodes = arrayFilter(oldNode.children || [], function(node) {return node != null;}),
                childElements = arrayFilter(fiber.props.children || [], function(node) {return node != null;}),
                length = Math.max(oldChildNodes.length, childElements.length),children = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var childNode = this._reconcile(oldNode.dom, oldChildNodes[i], childElements[i]);
                children.push(childNode);
            }
            return children;
        }
        Maker.prototype._props = function(node, oldProps, newProps) {
            for (var prop in oldProps) {
                if (!(prop in newProps)) {
                    if (prop === "route") {
                        node.onclick = undefined;
                        if (node.tagName === "A") node.removeAttribute("href");
                        continue;
                    }
                    var _ = node && node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase(),
                        is_p = prop in node || prop.startsWith("$."),
                        is_s = _ in $Maker.svgs;
                    if (is_p && !is_s) node[prop.startsWith("$.") ? prop.substring(2) : prop] = undefined;
                    else node.removeAttribute(prop);
                }
            }
            for (var event in node._listener) {
                if (!(event in newProps)) {
                    var ev = event.split(":"),
                        eventName = ev[0].substring(1);
                    node.removeEventListener(eventName, node._listener[event]);
                    delete node._listener[event];
                }
            }
            for (var prop in newProps) {
                if (prop === "route") {
                    var link = newProps[prop];
                    node.onclick = function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $Navigate(link);
                    }
                    if (node.tagName === "A") node.href = link;
                    continue;
                }
                if (prop === "children") continue;
                if (prop === "style") {
                    if (Verify.obj(newProps[prop])) this._style(node, newProps[prop]);
                    else node.style = newProps[prop];
                    continue;
                }
                var _ = node && node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase(),
                    is_p = prop in node || prop.startsWith("$."),
                    is_o = prop.split(".").length > 1,
                    is_e = prop.startsWith("@"),
                    is_s = _ in $Maker.svgs,
                    is_r = prop === "ref";
                if (is_e) {
                    this._event(node, prop, newProps[prop]);
                    continue;
                }
                if (is_p && !is_s) {
                    node[prop.startsWith("$.") ? prop.substring(2) : prop] = newProps[prop];
                    continue;
                }
                if (is_o) {
                    var _ = arrayReduce(prop.split("."), function(a, e) {
                        return e.length ? a + `["${e}"]` : a;
                    }, "");
                    eval(`node${_} = newProps[prop]`);
                    continue;
                }
                if (is_r) {
                    if (this.refs[newProps[prop]])
                        Verify.arr(this.refs[newProps[prop]]) ?
                        this.refs[newProps[prop]].push(node) :
                        (this.refs[newProps[prop]] = [this.refs[newProps[prop]], node]);
                    else this.refs[newProps[prop]] = node;
                    continue;
                }
                node.setAttribute(prop, newProps[prop]);
            }
        }
        Maker.prototype._style = function(node, props) {
            for (var key in props) {
                var prop = $HELPERS.kebabCase(key),
                    cur = props[key];
                if (prop.startsWith("--")) {
                    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(prop, cur);
                } else if (Verify.present(cur)) {
                    Verify.nbr(cur) && !(prop in $Maker.css) && (cur += "px");
                    node.style[prop] = cur;
                }
            }
        }
        Maker.prototype._event = function(node, name, callback) {
            var self = this,
                isSameFunction = false,
                ev = name.split(":"),
                eventName = ev[0].substring(1);
            var fn = function(e) {
                self._break(ev, e);
                callback(e);
            }
            node._listener = node._listener || {};
            if (node._listener[name] && node._listener[name].toString() === fn.toString()) {
                isSameFunction = true;
                return;
            }
            if (!isSameFunction) {
                node._listener[name] = fn;
                node.addEventListener(eventName, fn);
            }
        }
        Maker.prototype._break = function(types, event) {
            types.forEach(function(type) {
                switch (type) {
                    case "prevent":
                        event.preventDefault();
                    case "propagation":
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    case "immediate":
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }
            });
        }
        Maker.prototype.exec = function(tree) {
            this.refs = {};
            this.tree = tree || this.tree;
            this.instance = this._reconcile(this.container, this.instance, this.tree);
        }
        return Maker;
    })();
    var Class = (function() {
        var memory = [],
            defineSrc = function(self, object, fn, vr, ext) {
                Object.defineProperty(object, "src", {
                    get() {
                        return this._src;
                    },
                    set(value) {
                        self._load = true;
                        if (!value) return null;
                        var _self = this;
                        value = value.replaceAll(".", "/");
                        this._src = "/views/" + value + ".dust." + ext;
                        self._run = false;
                        (async function() {
                            if (!memory[value]) {
                                var code = await fetch(_self._src);
                                memory[value] = await code.text();
                            }
                            self[vr] = memory[value];
                            await self[fn]();
                            self._load = false;
                        })();
                    },
                });
            },
            stateUpdate = function(object, callback) {
                const handler = {
                    get(target, property, receiver) {
                        const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, property);
                        if (desc && !desc.writable && !desc.configurable) {
                            return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
                        }
                        try {
                            return new Proxy(target[property], handler);
                        } catch (err) {
                            return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
                        }
                    },
                    defineProperty(target, property, descriptor) {
                        callback(property, descriptor.value);
                        return Reflect.defineProperty(target, property, descriptor);
                    },
                    deleteProperty(target, property) {
                        callback();
                        return Reflect.deleteProperty(target, property);
                    },
                };
                return new Proxy(object, handler);
            }

        function Class(props) {
            this._run = true;
            this.state = this._set(props.state);
            this.style = document.querySelector(props.style);
            this.container = document.querySelector(props.container);
            if (this.container) {
                var dust_code = document.getElementById(this.container.getAttribute("target"));
                this.code = dust_code ? dust_code.textContent : "";
                defineSrc(this, this.container, "_code", "code", "html");
                if (dust_code) {
                    dust_code.remove();
                    this.container.removeAttribute("target");
                }
                if (this.container.hasAttribute("src")) {
                    this.container.src = this.container.getAttribute("src");
                    this.container.removeAttribute("src");
                }
            }
            if (this.style) {
                var dust_sass = document.getElementById(this.style.getAttribute("target"));
                this.sass = dust_sass ? dust_sass.textContent : "";
                defineSrc(this, this.style, "_sass", "sass", "css");
                if (dust_sass) {
                    dust_sass.remove();
                    this.style.removeAttribute("target");
                }
                if (this.style.hasAttribute("src")) {
                    this.style.src = this.style.getAttribute("src");
                    this.style.removeAttribute("src");
                }
            }
            if (this._run) {
                this._sass();
                this._code();
            }
            var self = this;
            Class.Helper("state", function(state) {
                return self.setState(state);
            });
            execArrayFns(Class, "START_FNS");
        }
        Class.prototype.setState = function(state) {
            this.state = this._set(Object.assign({}, this.state, state));
            this._sass();
            this._code();
        }
        Class.prototype._set = function(state) {
            var self = this,
                _state = {};
            arrayEach(objectKeys(state), function(key) {
                if (Verify.fn(state[key])) _state[key] = state[key].bind(self);
                else _state[key] = state[key];
            });
            return stateUpdate(_state, function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    self._sass();
                    self._code();
                }, 0);
            });
        }
        Class.prototype._sass = function() {
            if (this.style) {
                const sass = new Preset(this.sass, this.state).string();
                const code = new Sass(sass).string();
                this.style.textContent = code;
            }
        }
        Class.prototype._code = async function() {
            const tree = await new Preset(this.code, this.state, true).exec();
            if (tree.length) {
                if (!this.maker) this.maker = new Maker(this.container);
                this.maker.exec(tree);
                execArrayFns(Class, "UPDATE_FNS");
            }
        }
        Class.Helper = function(name, fn) {
            if (arrayConcat(["loop", "self"], objectKeys($HELPERS)).includes(name)) throw new Error("reserved helper name (" + name + ")");
            $HELPERS[name] = fn;
        }
        Class.init = function(fn) {document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);}
        Class.start = function(fn) {this.START_FNS.push(fn);}
        Class.update = function(fn) {this.UPDATE_FNS.push(fn);}
        objectProperty(Class.prototype, "refs", {
            get() {return this.maker && this.maker.refs || {};}
        });
        Class.START_FNS = [];
        Class.UPDATE_FNS = [];
        return Class;
    })();
    var Router = (function() {
        var Load = { in: function() {
                document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<div class=\"__dust__loader__\" " +
                    "style=\"position:fixed;inset:0;background:#fff;display:flex;align-items:center;" +
                    "justify-content:center;font-size:24px;font-weight:600;z-index:9999;\">Loading...</div>");
                document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
            },
            out: function() {
                document.body.style.overflow = "";
                arrayFrom(document.querySelectorAll(".__dust__loader__"), function(load) {
                    load.remove();
                });
            }
        };
        function Router(props) {
            var self = this,
                container = props.container,
                style = props.style,
                routes = props.routes || [],
                state = props.state || {},
                match = arrayFind(routes, function(p) {return p.path === "/404";}) || {name: "404",path: "/404",view: "404",};
            this.routes = $Router.map(arrayConcat([match], arrayFilter(routes, function(e) {return e.path != "/404"; })));
            this.hash = props.hash || false;
            Class.Helper("navigate", function(path) { return self.navigate(path);});
            Class.Helper("route", function(name, object) { return self.route(name, object);});
            Class.Helper("match", function(name) { return self.match.route.name === name;});
            Class.Helper("params", function() { return self.params();});
            Class.Helper("queries", function() { return self.queries();});
            this.dust = new Class({container: container,style: style,state: state});
            if (this.hash && !location.hash) location.hash = "#/";
            window[this.hash ? "onhashchange" : "onpopstate"] = function() {
                self.navigate(self.hash ? location.hash.substring(1) : history.state.path);
            };
            this.navigate(this.hash ? location.hash.substring(1) : location.pathname);
            $Navigate = this.navigate.bind(this);
            execArrayFns(Router, "LOAD_FNS");
        }
        Router.prototype.navigate = function(path) {
            if (!history.state || history.state.path !== path) {
                history.pushState({path: path,}, document.title,(this.hash ? "#" : "") + path);
            }
            this.execute();
        }
        Router.prototype.route = function(name, object) {
            var _path = null,route = arrayFind(this.routes, function(r) {return r.name === name;});
            if (route) {
                var path = route.path,
                    queries = [],
                    regex = /{(\w+):\w+}/g;
                if (!Verify.obj(object)) {
                    _path = regex.test(path) ? path.replace(regex, object) : path + (object ? ("?" + object) : "");
                } else {
                    _path = path.replace(regex, function(_, s) {
                        var value = object[s] || "";
                        delete object[s];
                        return value;
                    });
                    for (var key in object) queries.push(key + "=" + object[key]);
                    _path = _path + (queries.length ? "?" + queries.join("&") : "");
                }
            }
            return _path;
        }
        Router.prototype.params = function() {return $Router.params(this.match);}
        Router.prototype.queries = function() {
            var params = new URLSearchParams(this.hash ? location.hash.split("?")[1] || "" : location.search),
                obj = {};
            arrayEach(arrayFrom(new Set(params.keys())), function(key) {
                obj[key] = params.getAll(key).length > 1 ? params.getAll(key) : params.get(key);
            });
            return obj;
        }
        Router.prototype.execute = async function() {
            Load.in();
            this.match = $Router.match(this);
            var self = this,
                route = this.match.route,
                fnCall = function() {
                    self.dust._load ? requestAnimationFrame(fnCall) :
                        route.fn.call(self) && execArrayFns(Router, "NEXT_FNS");
                }
            guard = route.guard.bind(this);
            if (Verify.fn(guard) && Verify.present(await guard())) {
                execArrayFns(Router, "PREV_FNS");
                this.dust.container.src = route.view;
                fnCall()
            }
            Load.out();
        }
        Router.prototype.setState = function(state) {this.dust.setState(state);}
        Router.load = function(fn) {this.LOAD_FNS.push(fn);}
        Router.prev = function(fn) {this.PREV_FNS.push(fn);}
        Router.next = function(fn) {this.NEXT_FNS.push(fn);}
        objectProperty(Router.prototype, "refs", {
            get() { return this.dust && this.dust.refs || {};}
        });
        objectProperty(Router.prototype, "state", {
            get() {return this.dust && this.dust.state || {}; }
        });
        Router.Helper = Class.Helper;
        Router.LOAD_FNS = [];
        Router.PREV_FNS = [];
        Router.NEXT_FNS = [];
        return Router;
    })();
    Class.Sass = Sass;
    Class.Preset = Preset;
    Class.Jsx = Jsx;
    Class.Maker = Maker;
    Class.Router = Router;
    return Class;
})();
```

Comment: is this code or the github link code the code in need of review?

Comment: this is just a sample code the full code is on github

Comment: the code is working corectly i just need some advice about performence and i am using third-party site becode the code is over the chars limit

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! If you are concerned about the size of your code, bear in mind that [the character limit on CR was increased to 65k](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7163/120114).